# Need help creating a Javascript regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I have to validate a url in the following way:

- cannot contain protocol e.g. http or https
- if it's localhost, then it must have a port e.g. localhost:4200
- if it's not localhost, it must have a top level domain e.g. .com .net etc

examples of valid urls:

```
my-site.com
www.my-site.com
localhost:4200
```

examples of invalid urls:

```
https://my-site.com
localhost
www.my-site
```

Comment: There are *hundreds* of top-level domains

Comment: That said, your specs are impossible to satisfy with a single regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of one expression to rule them all, why don't you just step-wise validate what you know?

```js
const validateUrl = (url) => {
  if (/^https?/.test(url)) return false;
  if (/^localhost/.test(url)) return /:\d+$/.test(url);
  return /^[\w.-]+(?:\.[\w]+)+$/.test(url);
};

const valid = [ 'my-site.com', 'www.my-site.com', 'localhost:4200' ];
const invalid = [ 'https://my-site.com', 'localhost', 'www.my-site' ];

const test = (msg, res) => console.log(`${msg}: ${res ? 'pass' : 'fail'}`);

test('Valid', valid.every(url => validateUrl(url)));
test('Invalid', invalid.every(url => !validateUrl(url)));
```